# Convert CSV column of strings to integers with CSV lib in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, csv, sed

So I have a CSV with two columns that contain dollar amounts in string format. `head -n 5 file.csv` reveals the following:

```
Title,Distributor Long Name,Wk,Estimated Weekend Gross,Cume,Locs Reported,Avg/Loc,Booking Title #
"=""Zero Dark Thirty""","=""Sony""",4,"24,000,000","29,480,807",2937,"8,172","=""66273"""
"=""Haunted House, A""","=""Open Road""",1,"18,817,000","18,817,000",2160,"8,712","=""71209"""
"=""Gangster Squad""","=""Warner Bros.""",1,"16,710,000","16,710,000",3103,"5,385","=""66556"""
"=""Django Unchained""","=""The Weinstein Company""",3,"11,065,000","125,399,122",3012,"3,674","=""66122"""
```

This goes on for about 40 rows. You'll notice two of the columns — the "Estimated Weekend Gross" and "Cume" ones — have their values as **strings**.

So my question is, is there a way to iterate over only these two columns, convert the string values to integers doing something like `row.to_s.gsub(',','').to_i` and then overwrite those values to their respective rows in the **same** CSV?

I tried doing something like this, but I'm not getting a properly formatted CSV..

```
File.open('modified.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('original.csv') do |row|
    csv << row[0].to_s.gsub('=','').gsub(', The','')
    csv << row[3].to_s.gsub(',','').to_i
    csv << row[4].to_s.gsub(',','').to_i
  end
end
```

I've also played around with `:headers => :integer` when doing the block, but it won't let me convert the values from strings to integers. So, what am I missing? Should I store these values and then write a new CSV or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaron, just change the row and write it to your new file like this

```
require 'csv'

File.open('modified.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('original.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    row['Estimated Weekend Gross'] = row['Estimated Weekend Gross'].delete(',').to_i
    row['Cume'] = row['Cume'].delete(',').to_i
    csv << row
  end
end
```

EDIT: if you want to save the headers in modified.csv you can do it like this, but there must be a shorter way without opening the file twice, if someone has a better solution for this ?

```
headers = CSV.open('original.csv', 'r', :headers => true).read.headers
CSV.open('modified.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << headers
  CSV.foreach('original.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    row['Estimated Weekend Gross'] = row['Estimated Weekend Gross'].delete(',').to_i
    row['Cume'] = row['Cume'].delete(',').to_i
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked out quite well. I'll be on the lookout for a solution that doesn't have as many I/O operations, but this works for my purposes. Thanks @peter!

Comment: thanks for the clear and documented question, i enjoyed it, could you accept the answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this:

```
sed 's/,\("[^"]*"\)*/|\1/g' file.csv | awk -F"|" '{s="";for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){if (i==4 || i==5){gsub("\,","",$i);gsub("\"","",$i);s=s","$i;}else{if (i>1){s=s","$i;}else{s=s""$i;}}}print s;}' -
```

I got this output:

```
"=""Zero Dark Thirty""","",4,24000000,29480807,2937,"8,172",""
"=""Haunted House, A""","",1,18817000,"18,817,000",2160,"8,712",""
"=""Gangster Squad""","",1,16710000,16710000,3103,"5,385",""
"=""Django Unchained""","",3,11065000,125399122,3012,"3,674",""
```

I know it is hard to understand, so I will explain it step by step:

1. First of all create put a separator to each field taking into account the quotes with:

   sed 's/,("[^"]*")*/|\1/g' file.csv

And you will get a pipe separator "|" between each field:

```
"=""Zero Dark Thirty"""|""|4|"24,000,000"|"29,480,807"|2937|"8,172"|""
"=""Haunted House| A"""|""|1|"18,817,000"|"18,817,000"|2160|"8,712"|""
"=""Gangster Squad"""|""|1|"16,710,000"|"16,710,000"|3103|"5,385"|""
"=""Django Unchained"""|""|3|"11,065,000"|"125,399,122"|3012|"3,674"|""
```

1. Once you get this output using pipe as field separator, you can use awk to apply the described filter to fields 4 and 5 (it should be run after sed command because it takes sed's output as input):

   awk -F"|" '{s="";for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){if (i==4 || i==5){gsub("\,","",$i);gsub("\"","",$i);s=s","$i;}else{if (i>1){s=s","$i;}else{s=s""$i;}}}print s;}' -

Removing quotes and commas for each field (as an integer representation), and getting your desired output:

```
"=""Zero Dark Thirty""","",4,24000000,29480807,2937,"8,172",""
"=""Haunted House, A""","",1,18817000,"18,817,000",2160,"8,712",""
"=""Gangster Squad""","",1,16710000,16710000,3103,"5,385",""
"=""Django Unchained""","",3,11065000,125399122,3012,"3,674",""
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
CSV.open('modified.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('original.csv') do |row|
    modified_row = row.clone
    modified_row[0] = row[0].to_s.gsub('=','').gsub(', The','')
    modified_row[3] = row[3].to_s.gsub(',','').to_i
    modified_row[4] = row[4].to_s.gsub(',','').to_i
    csv << modified_row
  end
end
```

I changed the file opening for writing to use CSV, and then corrected the appending to append the array of a row line instead of appending individual values.